# Positioning markers over the top of clusters; z-index not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got some JSON data populating markers and then clustering using MarkerClusterer.  I also have some alert type markers that don't cluster on purpose.  Could someone please help me out with how to get the alert markers to display over the top of the cluster markers?

I've tried setting a z-index on the marker and using .getZIndex() returns the z-index I set however no matter how high I set it it's always positioned under the cluster marker.

Is there some sort of magic I'm missing?  The clusters are created before the alerts.

Thank you

Comment: what are alert type markers? info boxes?

Comment: Just normal markers with a custom graphic with a big ! on them so they stand out.  They always appear lower than the clustered marker.

Comment: Ok, so I've found that it's not possible to do what I'm after as the clusters sit in overlayMouseTarget above the markers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because clustered markers sit in the overlayMouseTarget pane, you would need to create your own markers in the same pane.

If you create a custom overlay (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#CustomOverlays) and add it to the overlayMouseTarget pane, you should be able to make the markers appear above the clustered markers using the CSS zIndex property.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's correct, but I changed the JavaScript I downloaded to use `floatPane` instead of `overlayImage` and it works great.