# rendering order of multiple MarkerClusterers

Tags: google-maps, markerclusterer

I have two groups of data points, each clustered with its own MarkerClusterer instance. I thought that, if clusters/markers from the two sets happened to overlap, the one on top would belong to the clusterer I instantiated last; and it seems to work that way, mostly. But occasionally, the wrong pin comes out on top. Is that because the clusterers render asynchronously? Is there a way I can control this?

Comment: What about providing a [mcve]?

Comment: @MrUpsidown It's not easy, being sporadic. But I think what you are saying is that, whatever this behaviour is, it is not the correct behaviour. That'll do me, thank you.

Comment: No I haven't said such a thing and without being able to see the behavior that you mentioned, it's hard to tell, hence my request for a [mcve]. In any case, Markers ordering on the Z axis is controlled by their `z-index` property.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Thank you again. I am working on a test dataset, and, once complete, I will either convince myself that I was dreaming, or be able to reproduce this behaviour, in which case will submit it for inspection at once.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I finally formulated the right questions and found useful information, which I post as the answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that marker pins are placed in a different MapPane than the cluster pins, and the MapPanes are controlled by z-index order of their own. [About the MapPanes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays#initialize).

Of further interest: [to make the markers' z-index work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845916/google-maps-marker-zindex-doesnt-work-for-two-icon-types-symbol-and-string),

> You have to both specify a zIndex and add
>       *optimized: false*
>   to every marker constructor

And [to make marker pins and cluster pins respect the same z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894548/positioning-markers-over-the-top-of-clusters-z-index-not-working):

> Because clustered markers sit in the overlayMouseTarget pane, you
>   would need to create your own markers in the same pane.